# Convert array to numpy datetime64

Tags: python, numpy, date

```
dates_arr = [['2000', '01', '01'], ['2000', '01', '02'], ['2000', '01', '03'], ['2000', '01', '04'], ['2000', '01', '05']]
dates_arr = np.array(dates_arr)
```

Trying to convert this into datetime64.

```
dates = dates_arr.astype("datetime64[D]")
```

```
dates = np.full([len(dates_arr),3], dates_arr, dtype='datetime64[D]')
```

Both result in the same output.

```
[['2000-01-01' '0001-01-01' '0001-01-01']
 ['2000-01-01' '0001-01-01' '0002-01-01']
 ['2000-01-01' '0001-01-01' '0003-01-01']
 ['2000-01-01' '0001-01-01' '0004-01-01']
 ['2000-01-01' '0001-01-01' '0005-01-01']]
```

I don't understand why it's working this way.

Comment: You did not provide what is 'days' in your code: days_array = np.full([len(dates_arr),3], days, dtype='datetime64[D]'). Also, please provide a minimal example of codes which is able to run since I'm also getting the error 'list' object has no attribute 'astype'.

Comment: @MinhNguyen I've edited my question. I was changing variable names to make it easier to understand and didn't realise I missed steps.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get what I needed by flattening the list and joining, but there is probably a better way to do it.

```
dates_arr = [['2000', '01', '01'], ['2000', '01', '02'], ['2000', '01', '03'], ['2000', '01', '04'], ['2000', '01', '05']]
dates_arr = ["-".join(dates) for dates in dates_arr]
dates_arr = [np.datetime64(x) for x in dates_arr]
dates_arr = np.array(dates_arr)
dates = np.full([len(dates_arr)], dates_arr, dtype='datetime64[D]')
```

Output

```
['2000-01-01' '2000-01-02' '2000-01-03' '2000-01-04' '2000-01-05']
```